# Как отправлять боту в Telegram команду "/start" при помощи Uptimerobot чтоб он не засыпал каждые 30 минут на Heroku?

Tags: telegram-bot, запрос, request, heroku, update

Залил Telegram-бота на хостинг Heroku. Однако, там есть одна неприятная мелочь - если к боту не обращаются каждые 30 минут - он засыпает. Поэтому хочу "тормошить" своего бота каждые 5 минут, отправляя ему команду \start с помощью сервиса Uptimerobot. Я заполнил все данные вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно заполнить поля так, чтобы боту каждые 5 минут приходили сообщения. Я в этом новичок и ничего не понимаю. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UptimeRobot` работает только для веб-сервисов - если, допустим, на `Heroku` находится веб-сайт. Он не способен отправить сообщение в `Telegram`. Поэтому есть 2 способа выхода из ситуации:

1. Купить `VPS` и развернуть бота там.
2. Добавить в код, отвечающий за бота, веб-компонент (например, запустить веб-сервер `Flask` при старте) и обращаться по `URL`, который присвоен приложению на `Heroku`.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня в самом боте находится база данных. И в основном страдает она, так как все данные стираются из-за засыпания приложения. Можете подсказать онлайн базы данных, на которые я могу осуществить миграцию чтобы мои данные были в целости?

Comment: MongoDB выдают бесплатный сервер

Comment: Но это БД на любителя

Comment: И забыл: был еще плагин PostgreSQL для Heroku. Бесплатный.